# Manner of correcting spouse

Tags: islamic-basis, husband-wife, behavior, adab, respect

In response to behaviour that is unappealing to him and perhaps negative in general, what evidence is there of the manner in which a husband gives his wife necessary guidance about her behaviour (or as some may say corrects her behaviour).